# How to clone a USB flash drive using dd?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, clone

Using 'dd' to clone a USB drive

-cfdisk:

resized the destination partition to be of same size

made the partition bootable

same 'type' ext3

ran 'mkfs.ext3' after exit cfdisk

then

dd if=dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1

result booting:  Missing operating system.

The source USB device boots on multiple laptops

USB destination filesystem looks the same....

Any idears?

Comment: Why are you gooing through all the effort to setup partitions and filesystems?  Just copy the entire disk.  dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb

Comment: You are probably right, but this is the result...the 2nd USB is slightly smaller in size

dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
dd: writing to `/dev/sdb': No space left on device
15654849+0 records in
15654848+0 records out
8015282176 bytes (8.0 GB) copied, 3430.66 s, 2.3 MB/s

Comment: then you have to first resize the partition on the originating drive soi that it won't end after the end of the device after clone, after that it's just simple `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=8192` and ignoring the error

Answer (score 7):

I recently had to clone a 32gb trancend thumbdrive onto another. My drive is a multiboot with additional software so I didn't want to just copy all files on the FS. DD was a clear choice, but I was on windows.

I had cygwin installed and did the following.

first I had to figure out what /dev/sdX device my f: volume was. To do so run this command in cygwin. (TIP: Make sure you start cygwin with admin privs.. *Right click on cygwin and "Run as Administrator")

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

which should output:

```
   8 0 3813383838 sda
   8 1       4031 sda3 C:\
   8 15  30588303 sdb 
   8 15  30588303 sdb1 E:\
   8 21  30530020 sdc
   8 22  30530020 sdc1 F:\
```

etc... 
Here you can clearly see for me to clone my F: drive to my E: drive I'd issue the following command.

```
dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/sdb bs=8M
```

My image was 32gb.. and I didn't want to just sit and wait with a blinking cursor.. I wanted to see progress so I installed "pv" in cygwin.

```
dd if=/dev/sdc | pv | dd of=/dev/sdb bs=8M
```

Hope this helps

Comment: To follow the progress of the copy, no need to use `pv`, just add the `status=progress` option to your command : dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/sdb bs=8M status=progress

Answer (score 5):

You copied the partition, but not the MBR. Copy the first 446 bytes of the device itself.

Comment: Is this correct?

dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1

Comment: No, that will wipe the partition table as well. And I'm not psychic, so I don't know if those are the correct devices. You're definitely on the right track though.

Comment: it shouldn't wipe the partition table. something like `dd if=/dev/sda of=/tmp/thumbdrive.img bs=512` would create a file, and then you could use that file to make X clones of your thumb drive, with `dd if=/tmp/thumbdrive.img of=/dev/sda bs=512`

Comment: Everything past byte 440 is unique to the drive and should not be copied. And I speak not only from experience... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record

Comment: As the story goes....did dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1, tried booting from it...All I got was 'GRUB' 
So then tried example from first comment of Zoredache above: result --> cfdisk /dev/sdb "FATAL ERROR Bad primary partition 1: Partition ends after end-of-disk
                          Press any key to exit cfdisk

back to my Pretty good friend Google.

Comment: 'should not' be copied? you're cloning the thumb drive, i've done similar things in the past, and granted it's been a long time, but i don't seem to remember any issues of two thumb drives sharing the same MBR, bit for bit. MentalBlister: DROP THE `count=1` you're only copying the first 512 bytes with `count=1` get rid of the count parameter completely.

Comment: Sharing, no. But if you already have partitions that you don't want to affect then just take the part before the table.

Comment: It's probably easier to just make the partition and write a standard boot-sector all in one command; checkout `man fdisk` for your OS's exact command. On mine `fdisk -BI /dev/da0` would put one partition with a standard boot-sector on the first USB device.

Answer (score 1):

If the drives are the same size, why not just clone *the entire drive*?

`dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=(whatever) count=(whatever)`

I've used this to clone HP ThinState configuration disks for HP thin clients that "don't work" with devices over 2GB - so long as I have a small enough drive to use as a master, I can clone it onto e.g. a 4GB drive and the thin client will happily boot from it.

Edit: Reading the above on "unique" IDs in/near the MBR, I don't see a problem with cloning an identical device if it's truly a clone - as long as you don't try to copy things between the two.

Comment: The devices are not the same, though they are supposed to be the same size 8 GB.

Comment: Use the smaller of the two as the master and the unfilled space won't matter. Using the larger of the two as the master... could have problems.

Comment: I've run in to this same issue, where two 64GB drives are actually 62.8GB and 63.4GB respectively. They have the same interface (USB3) and are the same brand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sfdisk to backup the partition table, then copy th boot sector (first block).  Then restore the partition table with sfdisk.  If you are using a DOS MBR, then the mbr program will write the MBR code onto the USB for you.